# mahapps dialogs in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mahapps.metro

I want to show a progress dialog with a user friendly message while am retrieving 
data. am using visual studio 2010. i tried using this code

```
/// <summary>
    /// Shows a progress message to the user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="header">The header text for the dialog.</param>
    /// <param name="message">The message to be displayed in the dialog.</param>
    void ShowProgressMessage(string header, string message)
    {
        _isMessageDialogVisible = true;

        _controller = _metroWindow.ShowProgressAsync(header, message);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Closes a message dialog that is visible.
    /// </summary>
    void CloseProgressMessage()
    {
        if (_isMessageDialogVisible)
        {
            _isMessageDialogVisible = false;
            if (null != _controller)
            {
                var controller = _controller.Result;
                controller.CloseAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

but it gives an error that says:

```
22 09 2015 [9] DEBUG - OPGSpiral Error App.AppDispatcherUnhandledException --- System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

at MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.BaseMetroDialog.HandleTheme()
   at MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.BaseMetroDialog.Initialize()
   at MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.BaseMetroDialog..ctor(MetroWindow owningWindow, MetroDialogSettings settings)
   at MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.ProgressDialog..ctor(MetroWindow parentWindow, MetroDialogSettings settings)
   at MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.ProgressDialog..ctor(MetroWindow parentWindow)
   at MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.DialogManager.<>c__DisplayClass43.b__3b()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
22 09 2015 [9] DEBUG - OPGSpiral Error App.AppDispatcherUnhandledException --- System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.BaseMetroDialog.HandleTheme()
   at MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.BaseMetroDialog.Initialize()
   at MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.BaseMetroDialog..ctor(MetroWindow owningWindow, MetroDialogSettings settings)
   at MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.ProgressDialog..ctor(MetroWindow parentWindow, MetroDialogSettings settings)
   at MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.ProgressDialog..ctor(MetroWindow parentWindow)
   at MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.DialogManager.<>c__DisplayClass43.b__3b()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

Comment: this bug is fixed in the alpha version, also available via NuGet

Comment: @punker76 any way of fixing it in current stable?

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in 1.2.2 which is available via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MahApps.Metro/).